# Aldol Reaction on an intermediate

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aldol-reaction

I was given the following reaction to prove a mechanism for:

[image]

and I managed to prove the first step with ease. 
[image]

The second step, forming the "base-catalysed aldol" is the part that's rather confusing me.

Consider the mechanism of a base-catalysed aldol reaction below.

[image]

For this reaction to take place, I need a second carbonyl molecule, but the $\ce{CO2Me}$ on the right hand side ring appears untouched, and likewise so does the carbonyl group on the left hand side too.

I tried the reaction a second way (giving the mechanism below) but am unsure if this is correct. 
**Is this the correct mechanism?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks mostly reasonable to me. There’s an alkene missing from your final product though. Also, in the final elimination you’ve drawn an E2 reaction, but OH typically isn’t a good enough leaving group to do this. Can you think of an alternative elimination pathway?